# How can I find and store how many columns it takes to reach a value greater than the first value in each row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = {'a': [3,4,5], 'b': [1,2,3], 'c': [4,3,3], 'd': [1,5,4], 'e': [9,4,6]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
dg = {'b': [2,3,4]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dg, columns = ['b'])
```

Original dataframe is df1. For each row, I want to find the first time a value is bigger than the value in the first column and store it in a new dataframe.

```
df1
    a   b   c   d   e
0   3   1   4   1   9
1   4   2   3   5   4
2   5   3   3   4   6
```

df2 is the resulting dataframe. For example, for df1 row 1; the first value is 3 and the first value bigger than 3 is 4 (column c). Hence in df2 row 1, we store 2 (there are two columns from column a to c). For df1 row 2, the first value is 4 and the first value bigger than 4 is 5 (column d). Hence in df2 row 2, we store 3 (there are three columns from column a to d). For df1 row 3, the first value is 5 and the first value bigger than 5 is 6 (column e). Hence in df2 row 3, we store 4 (there are four columns from column a to e).

```
df2

    b
0   2
1   3
2   4
```

I would appreciate the help.

Comment: You seem to have more than one problem here: (a) designing your algorithm -- which you've mostly done; (b) converting the algorithm steps to Python / PANDAS; (c) making it work *well*, using data frame operations.  Just where in this process are you stuck?  Please focus on *that* question, supplying code and results up to that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case we can do `sub` , if the value `gt` than 0 , we get the id with `idxmax`

```
s=df1.columns.get_indexer(df1.drop('a',1).sub(df1.a,0).ge(0).idxmax(1))
array([1, 1, 3])
df['New']=s
```

Comment: @user13599745 check the update ? also use your update information

Answer (score 1):

You can get the column names by comparing the entire DataFrame index wise against the first columns, replacing false values with NaNs and applying first_valid_index row wise, eg:

```
names = (
    df1.gt(df1.iloc[:, 0], axis=0)
    .replace(False, pd.NA) # or use np.nan
    .apply(pd.Series.first_valid_index, axis=1)
)
```

That'll give you:

```
0    c
1    d
2    e
```

Then you can convert those to offsets:

```
offsets = df1.columns.get_indexer(names)
#  array([2, 3, 4])
```